# Reduce the Compound Proposition to a Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I would like to know how to reduce the following compound proposition to a Conjunctive Normal Form please?

$$(P∨Q)→(R∧(S∧T))$$

Comment: Hint: Start by replacing $A \rightarrow B$ with $\lnot A \lor B$

Comment: like this ¬(P∨Q)∨(R∧S∧T)?

Comment: any hint how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1 : replace $A\implies B$ by $\lnot A \lor B$

step 2 : replace $\lnot(A\lor B)$ by $\lnot A\land\lnot B$ and $\lnot(A\land B)$ by $\lnot A\lor\lnot B$

step 3 : use distributivity of $\land$ relatively to $\lor$, that is $(A\land B)\lor C=(A\lor C)\land(B\lor C)$

step 4 : use associativity of $\land$ to remove some superfluous parenthesis

Normally you should get this 3 km long formula...

$(\lnot P\lor R)\land(\lnot Q\lor R)\land (\lnot P\lor S)\land(\lnot Q\lor S)\land (\lnot P\lor T)\land(\lnot Q\lor T)$

Comment: I'm lost, couldn't get it right yet, can you help?